# Efficient method of measuring total harmonic distortion

Tags: operational-amplifier, distortion, total-harmonic-distortion

I have been trying to create a set-up for measuring (estimating) the reported total harmonic distortion of an op-amp. (Please don't ask why I don't use a spectrum analyzer because I have been assigned to create a set-up for that.)
I have been checking the datasheet of some op-amps that reported THD or second and third order harmonic distortion. They have been mainly using fundamental frequencies of 1kHz([NJU7047](https://www.mouser.com/datasheet/2/294/NJU7046_NJU7047_NJU7048_E-1917517.pdf)), 10kHz([LT1222](https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/1222fc.pdf)) and 1MHz([OPAx357](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2357.pdf?ts=1709532647627&ref_url=https%253A%252F%252Fwww.google.com%252F)). I want to assume that my set-up can do measurement for these fundamental frequencies only.

My initial question is: Why are these low frequencies that are well below gain bandwidth product of the op-amps chosen as the fundamental?

And about the set-up itself, I thought about a notch filter in the output of the amplifier under test to delete the fundamental frequency. then, have 3 buffer amplifiers with different gains corresponding to each harmonic. All the inputs of these buff amplifiers tied together to the output of the notch filter. Then there is an RC filter at the output of each buffer amplifier with the cut-off frequency of the specified harmonic.
My problem is an RC filter can't provide enough attenuation from say 1kHz to 2kHz and I need to cascade more low-pass RC stages.

If I want to generalize my set-up a little and as I mentioned above, make the design capable of working with 3 different fundamental frequencies, I need a lot of resistors and capacitors tuning both in the notch filter and the filter stages which would make the design inefficient especially if I aim to measure up to 5 harmonics distortion.

Now, the question is how to make this somehow more efficient? because the filters components tuning seems inevitable to me. And since there is a need for sharp filters, there is also many stages and many components!
Maybe there is a more innovative way to do this like what is actually used in spectrum analyzers.
Any comments or other possible ways to measure THD could help.

Comment: You can also use a DFT and calculate "harmonics" ... You just need a good and regular "sampling" ... and a good ADC.

Comment: @Antonio51 that's right but I need to have a hardware solution.

Comment: Don't forget you need at least components at 0.1% ... or more precise.

Comment: @Antonio51 for the filter cut-off frequencies to be somewhat exact? resistors wit 0.1% are available but capacitors...I'm not sure

Comment: you need to make at least 60 dB rejection, resistors and capacitors "paired".

Comment: @Antonio51 where does the minimum 60dB rejection come from?

Comment: If you want to measure harmonics with some precision (say 0.1 %), then you have to "meet" this same precision with components (just a thought, must do some simulation). Here is a link for some capacitors https://datasheets.kyocera-avx.com/C0GNP0-KGM.pdf

Answer (score 2):

Filter type harmonic distortion analyzers notch the fundamental and then measure whatever is left. What you need for this is a very sharp notch filter, typically a Twin-T or Wien Bridge filter would be used. You would either need a notch filter for each fundamental frequency and switch in whichever one was needed, or a tunable filter with several ranges to be able to cover the frequency span you're after.

Once you've filtered the fundamental you need to measure how much energy is left in the signal, which would probably involve amplifying and rectifying it. You would also need to calibrate it to give a meaningful result dependent on the input signal level.

As to why those fundamental frequencies were chosen, they would be within the range that you would expect an opamp to operate at. Usually for THD you're interested in audio, so 1 kHz is a common frequency to test at. Also, it wouldn't do much good to use a frequency that is near the gain bandwidth product of the amp because then the harmonics would all fall at multiples of that.

Comment: what you mentioned about amplifying and rectifying gives total harmonic distortion. But as I said some op-amps report 2nd and 3rd harmonic distortion separately or as the datasheet says HD2 and HD3, such as OPAx357.  This would need sharp band pass filters for each harmonic and each fundamental frequency. this creates many capacitors and resistors to be tuned. @GodJihyo

Comment: For 2nd and 3rd harmonic bandpass filters you could use Twin-T or Wien bridge, these  don't take many components.

Comment: So for 1 kHz you need a 1 kHz notch, a 2 kHz bandpass and a 3 kHz bandpass. With Twin-T that's 9 resistors and 9 caps for the frequency determining components. With Wien Bridges it would be 6 of each.

Comment: yeah, bandpass filters included. 2 other fundamental frequencies also included.. I end up with a lot of component! :(

Comment: @Fateme How many components were you expecting? I wouldn’t consider a few dozen resistors and capacitors to be a lot.

Answer (score 1):

It's quite tricky. Back in analogue days this was usually done with a very clean sine wave (usually a [Wien bridge oscillator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien_bridge_oscillator) which tends to have very low distortion) and then some tunable filter circuitry to reject the oscillator. What is left over is THD+N (Total Harmonic Distortion plus Noise), and if your noise is much less than the distortion, well it's really THD.

Very often the filter adjustment was manual and often rather sensitive to get a minimum on the output reading. Although THD at 1kHz is often quoted, many devices will be almost unmeasurably low at that level, so 10kHz readings were often more useful. Also you would want to drive the circuit under test as hard as possible to get some measurable results. So typically you were measuring an opamp circuit powered at +/-17V or so, with a level of +2-dBu. This means that any amplification circuits to get up that level also need to be very low distortion.

You might find it helpful to study [the schematics for the HP339 Audio Test Set](https://www.diyaudio.com/community/threads/hp-339a-distortion-analyzer-schematics-plus.399491/) which was one popular device for ideas about how to do this.